# JFreeChart Bar Chart dataset from database

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller, jfreechart, bar-chart

My goal is to generate [this Bar Chart](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo3differentcolorswithinaseries.htm) using JFreeChart.

I am trying to obtain JFreeChart data from database using MVC; Bean, Data Access Object (DAO) and Servlet. I have problem in doing code at Servlet. Below codes are what I have so far.

Help will be appeciate and thank you in advance! :)

**Database**

id | revenue

---

R1 | 999
M3 | 832
G7 | 318

**Bean**

```
public class Revenue
{
   private String id;
   private Integer revenue;

   //getters and setters
}
```

**DAO**

```
public ArrayList<Revenue> getAllRevenueList()
{
  try
  {
      //driver 
      //connection code 

     String sql = "SELECT id,revenue FROM revenue_table";
     Statement stmt = con.createStatemtnt();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

     ArrayList<Revenue> revenueList = new ArrayList<Revenue>();
     while(rs.next)
     {
        Revenue r = new Revenue();
        r.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        r.setRevenue(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("revenue")));
        revenueList.add(r);  //add object to list
     }

     return revenueList;
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return null;
  }
}
```

**Servlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("image/png");

        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
JFreeChart chart = getRevenueChart();

int width = 1100;
            int height = 350;
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outputStream, chart, width, height);


}

public JFreeChart getRevenueChart() {

//Cannot instantiate the type CategoryDataset

        CategoryDataset dataset = new CategoryDataset();

        ArrayList<Bean> revenueList = DAO.getAllRevenueList();

        if (revenueList != null && !revenueList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Bean r : revenueList) {
                dataset.setValue(r.getRevenue(), r.getID());

            }
        }

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Graph Title", 
                "ID", 
                "Revenue",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
                false,
                false,
                false);

        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        CategoryAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();

        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
        BarRenderer r = (BarRenderer) renderer;
        r.setMaximumBarWidth(0.95);

        return chart;
    }
```

Comment: So you have a problem with creating the chart? What have you tried? Or what should be all done in the Servlet? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem was to create the chart from given `List<Revenue>` then try something like the following.

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for (Revenue revenue : revenueList) {
  // the middle parameter is for naming the value, can be empty if you have just one
  dataset.addValue(revenue.getRevenue(), "", revenue.getId());
}

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
  "",
  "",
  "Revenues",
  dataset,
  PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
  true,
  false,
  false
);                // or whatever parameters you need
```

Info about the static factory method is [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createBarChart%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29).